# Live, real time video, compositing onto a virtual studio

Tags: rendering, camera, compositing-nodes, eevee-render-engine

Is there a way to use Blender and (say) a 3d virtual "tv studio", together with input streaming from a camera into the application in real time?

So, from a physical camera > USB input > here I am available in Blender as a stream of data by

My interest comes from a desire to create a live stream "tv studio" where the studio is a CG model and the actor is in a green screen studio.

Comment: I think it would need some serious computing power. And I don't know how this should be setup. I'm almost certain you'll have to create the software by yourself, or hire someone to do so. It would be awesome to see someone do this!

Comment: I was kinda hoping someone might pop up and say "hey, EEVEE renderer can do this!" (as it seems to support real time rendering of 3d objects so my brain sez "video stream is not even computed (much, and realtime video is already a thing), so it must be trivial to add a stream into a 3d scene (a 3d studio is not that complex as models go)".

Comment: Have you looked at https://obsproject.com/ ... I think you could pre-render the virtual studio in blender and then green screen your actor in using OBS

Answer (score 1):

You can do this after the fact, but unless you're running a supercomputer, Blender probably won't be able to keep up with the live feed.

Comment: natron will not work for this. you need a program like [Isadora](https://troikatronix.com)

Comment: Darn. Well, I tried. (:   (I don't have it myself, but have heard of it.)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it as an NDI source with a switcher like the tricaster mini, or maybe as others have done with the unreal engine or maybe like these guys. https://www.blendernation.com/2018/06/25/blender-used-in-hybrid-studio-pipeline/